# How do I create a nuget package with runtime dll?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I have a reference to LIB1.dll. This library need n dlls at runtime (LIB2.dll, LIB3.dll).
What I want to get is: having these libraries in the nuget package -> when I install the package they do not have to be added to the project, but must be moved to the building output folder.

If I put in a lib folder than nuget add those files to my project, and I would like to avoid it. If I put those files in the ref folder they are not added to the project but I don't have them in output folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
  </metadata>
      <files>
        <file src="lib\**" target="ref\lib" />
      </files>
    </package>
```